# Getting two different results by one SQL query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

First I am new to SQL and PHP.

I have created a simple social networking web app so users can post and follow others to see new posts from them.

At home page a user can first see posts from all users he is followong.

but what i want is to make the user see some other random popular posts that will be ordered by Likes.

here what i have done to get posts from users i follow:

```
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE author_id in 
 (SELECT followedID FROM follows WHERE
 followerID=:myID)
 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10
```

Now let's say you are following only 1 person. and that person has only one post. here you will see no more than a post!

That's why i want to show more posts when a user has already seen all posts.

i want some easy way to get other posts when the above query has done getting some specific posts.

This is the next query i'd like to execute.

```
SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY post_likes DESC LIMIT 10
```

Comment: Just use a UNION to do what you want.

Comment: @Ken Lee  will UNION execute the second query after the first  ends?

Comment: In your second query why use two order by clause. Please provide few sample data with both tables and expected output if possible.

Comment: See my answer below

Comment: @Rahul i wrote double ```ORDER BY``` by mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend `union`, because it incurs overhead for removing duplicates.

Instead, you can use a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM posts p LEFT JOIN
     follows f
     ON p.author_id = f.follows_id AND
        f.followerID = :myID
ORDER BY (f.follows_id IS NOT NULL) DESC,
         (CASE WHEN f.follows_id IS NOT NULL THEN p.id END),
         p.post_likes DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

The `ORDER BY` puts the followed posts first.  The other two clauses order each of the groups by the criteria you want.

Comment: I accepted your answer. the first answer is showing posts of people i follow first but doesn't order the other posts.  your code does all what i need correctly. and thank's.

Answer (score 1):

You may use UNION to do what you want

```
(SELECT * FROM posts WHERE author_id in 
 (SELECT followedID FROM follows WHERE
 followerID=:myID)
 ORDER BY id DESC limit 0,10) 
union
(SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY post_likes DESC limit 0,10)
LIMIT 0, 10
```

1. UNION will automatically append the 2nd query result to the 1st query result, and then show only the number of records specified by the LIMIT clause
2. Please note that union works only if the queries are of the same structure (which in this case is positive)
3. Please note that the use of parenthesis is mandatory if you use order by or limit or both
4. I have used 3 limit clauses (one for each query , and one for the final result of union) AND Both queries have ORDER BY clause. This is to make sure that the records extracted are what you want. (to show the followed posts *first*, and both are ordered properly)

Comment: yes i have tried it and it works fine thank's. this is my first time i use UNION  and please remove one of those ```ORDER BY``` because i wrote two by mistake

Comment: I will revise my answer further

Comment: that's perfect now❤

Comment: You are welcome. Please note that the use of parenthesis is mandatory if you use order by or limit or both; and I have used 3 limit clauses (one for each query , and one for the final result of union) to make sure that the records extracted are what you want.

Comment: @Gordon i used ```UNION``` then i got results that i want first  can you please give more details and also show any other way to do that?

Comment: @JihaneElberouhi . . . This query has no `order by` so the results are in an arbitrary order -- actually, the `UNION` will probably order the results based on *something* but you shouldn't depend on that.